# Internet Explorer dropdown without options displays large empty dropdown

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have an empty html select.

In Chrome and Firefox it correctly shows no elements in the dropdown list when you click it.

In Internet Explorer, clicking the dropdown arrow present an empty dropdown that looks about 10 rows long.

Why is Internet Explorer behaving like this and is there a fix?

Example code:

```
<select id="ExampleDropdown" name="ExampleDropdown"></select>
```

Example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s1e7ydf9/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, IE does it again, there is kind of a fix, if you put a blank option inside the select, it should give you a cross-browser blank select, [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s1e7ydf9/9/).

```
<select><option/></select>
```

---

You could also disable the select if it has no options and then enable it with JavaScript, [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s1e7ydf9/10/).

```
<select disabled></select>
```

And later on:

```
((select)).disabled = false;
```

---

Hope it helps, see ya!